# enable kubernetes authentication api on gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

It seems that in order to use the vault kubernetes auth backend, the authentication.k8s.io api must be enabled. GKE does not seem to have this enabled (/apis/authentication.k8s.io/ returns a 404)

Any idea why this is not enabled? From what i understand, this is not an alpha feature.
I am using kubernetes 1.7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that GKE does not turn on the TokenReview API (if you're managing your own Kubernetes cluster, then Javier's answer is the one to look at).

GKE is planning to turn on the APIs in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/

> Additionally, the API server must enable the authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1 API extensions group (--runtime-config=authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1=true).

I advise you to change that configuration on the api server and restart it.